# Why does the package \fontspec destroys the booklet setting?

Tags: packages, fontspec, polyglossia, booklet

I am trying to create a booklet with English and Russian in it. I could find a code for it that set all of the booklet aspects, but once I added a package to use the Russian alphabet, it destroyed the booklet format.

Here's what it should look like: [image]

But once I add the package `fontspec` it turned into this: [image]

Which I believe is not in landscape anymore. Here is the whole code I used:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{5.5in}{4in}{*}
\addtolength{\textheight}{\onelineskip}
\setlrmargins{2in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.25in}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet} \nofiles
\pagespersignature{16}
\ifpdf
\setpdftargetpages
\else
\setdvipstargetpages
\fi
\ifprintoption
\special{!TeXDict begin /landplus90{true}store end}
\special{!TeXDict begin <</Tumble true>> setpagedevice end}
\fi


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
Page one

страница один
\newpage
Page two

страница два
\newpage
Page three

страница три

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: What compiler are you using? In any case: In TeXlive 2017, your example compiles for me, using either pdflatex or lualatex, and produces the expected landscape layout.

Comment: I didn't add the error before, just the code without the package that made it not work. I just changed it so the end result is the first page in horizontal position and the rest in vertical position, reulting in part of the page not showing. I added the russian characters as that's my ultimate goal, to add the different alphabet to the booklet format. 
I use the online site Overleaf to compile.

Comment: What other way can I use to write with the russian alphabet and the english one without XeTeX, then?

Comment: LuaLaTeX uses utf-8 and is multilingual. However, egreg already posted a solution that is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a fault of `fontspec`, but rather of `booklet`.

When you compile with XeLaTeX, the macro `\setdvipstargetpages` is executed (because `\ifpdf` returns false), but this is meaningless for the engine. On the other hand, `\setpdftargetpages` is understood.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\settypeblocksize{5.5in}{4in}{*}
\addtolength{\textheight}{\onelineskip}
\setlrmargins{2in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.25in}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet} \nofiles
\pagespersignature{16}
\ifpdf
  \setpdftargetpages
\else
  \ifxetex
    \setpdftargetpages
  \else
    \setdvipstargetpages
  \fi
\fi
%\ifprintoption
%\special{!TeXDict begin /landplus90{true}store end}
%\special{!TeXDict begin <</Tumble true>> setpagedevice end}
%\fi


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
Page one
\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]